# 90% Winsorization on multiple variables

Tags: r

In my real data, I have multiple outliers for multiple variables. My data looks something like the example below but the numbers are completely random.
I would like to pull all data points that are greater than or less than 2 SD using a winsorization.

```
df<-read.table(header=T, text="id, group, test1, test2
1, 0, 57, 82
2, 0, 77, 80
3, 0, 67, 90
4, 0, 15, 70
5, 0, 58, 72
6, 1, 18, 44
7, 1, 44, 44
8, 1, 18, 46
9, 1, 20, 44
10, 1, 14, 38")
```

So far I have identified my outliers for the variables of test1 and test2 for each group using the following code:

```
outlier <- function(x, SD = 2){
  mu <- mean(x)
  sigma <- sd(x)
  out <- x < mu - SD*sigma | x > mu + SD*sigma
  out
}

# identify the outliers for each variable by each group
with(df, ave(test1, group, FUN = outlier))
with(df, ave(test2, group, FUN = outlier))

# add these new-found outliers to the data set
df$out1 <- with(df, ave(test1, group, FUN = outlier))
df$out2 <- with(df, ave(test2, group, FUN = outlier))
```

I am aware of the 'winsorize' function in the 'robustHD' package but am not sure:
1). how to tailor the command to a 90% winsorization (2 SD), 2). ensuring the winsorization accounts for the 2 different groups, 3). and including multiple variables in that winsorization.

Additionally, but not necessary...is there a way to see what the 'winsorize' function changed the numbers from to what the numbers were changed to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make first clear, how you want to winsorize your data. You have several options.

1. Use the mean+/-2sd limits as extreme values and replace all values outside by those
2. Use the observed value next to the mean+/-2sd limits
3. Use the 90% quantile

In option 1 and 3 you will possibly introduce values into your winsorized variable, which were not observed, in option 2 you will only have observed values. Note also, that the (5%, 95%)-quantile will not necessarily be near to 2*sd if you don't have reasonably well behaved normally distributed data.

For the winsorization process you can use `DescTools::Winsorize()`, which accepts both, probs and values for the limits.

Implementation 1)

```
x <- rnorm(100)
w1 <- Winsorize(x, 
                minval = mean(x) - 2*sd(x), 
                maxval = mean(x) + 2*sd(x))
```

For 2) you could use something like

```
w2 <- Winsorize(x, 
                minval = max(Coalesce(x[x <= mean(x)-2*sd(x)], mean(x)-2*sd(x))), 
                maxval = min(Coalesce(x[x >= mean(x)+2*sd(x)], mean(x)+2*sd(x))))
```

Provide some escalating values for cases where there are no values outside the limits. `Coalesce()` returns the first non empty value, so `Winsorize()` will always get a valid limit.

Option 3) is the default for the function

```
w3 <- Winsorize(x, probs=c(0.05, 0.95))
```

Define a function for the groupwise apply as (here for option 1):

```
df$w1 <- unsplit(
           tapply(df$test1, df$group,
                  function(x) Winsorize(x, 
                                        minval = mean(x) - 2*sd(x), 
                                        maxval = mean(x) + 2*sd(x)) )
         , f=df$group)
```

The replaced values can be found with

```
cbind(x, w1)[x!=w1,]
```

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful. I would like to use the first method since I have defined my outliers by being greater than 2SD...so to ensure I understand for my code it would something like `test1.winsorized<-Winsorize(test1, minval=mean(test1) - 2*sd(test1),maxval = mean(test1) + 2*sd(test1))`

Comment: Yes, go ahead! ;-)

Comment: I just want to double check...does this first method take into account the levels of factors? I do have two different groups under this variable...does this command account for the two levels of `group`

Comment: No, for the groupwise evaluation use the construct df$w1 <- unlist(tapply(… above!

Comment: I just used this for my real data and the code you provided changed all of the values of test1 rather than just the outliers `df$w1 <- unlist(tapply(df$test1, df$group, 
                   function(x) Winsorize(x, 
                                   minval = mean(x) - 2*sd(x), 
                                   maxval = mean(x) + 2*sd(x))
                       ))` any thoughts on why?

Comment: Ohh, yes, my fault. tapply() splits the vector by group and unlist does not reproduce the original order. I changed the solution using unsplit(). This should definitely work ok ..

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start - hopefully someone has a better solution for you.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~id, ~group, ~test1, ~test2,
  1,      0,     57,     82,
  2,      0,     77,     80,
  3,      0,     67,     90,
  4,      0,     15,     70,
  5,      0,     58,     72,
  6,      1,     18,     44,
  7,      1,     44,     44,
  8,      1,     18,     46,
  9,      1,     20,     44,
  10,      1,     14,     38
)
df
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>       id group test1 test2
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     1     0    57    82
#>  2     2     0    77    80
#>  3     3     0    67    90
#>  4     4     0    15    70
#>  5     5     0    58    72
#>  6     6     1    18    44
#>  7     7     1    44    44
#>  8     8     1    18    46
#>  9     9     1    20    44
#> 10    10     1    14    38

library(DescTools)
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(
    test2_winsorized = DescTools::Winsorize(
      test2,
      maxval = quantile(df$test2, 0.90),
      minval = quantile(df$test2, 0.10)
    ),
    test1_winsorized = DescTools::Winsorize(
      test1,
      maxval = quantile(df$test1, 0.90),
      minval = quantile(df$test1, 0.10)
    )
  )
#> # A tibble: 10 x 6
#> # Groups:   group [2]
#>       id group test1 test2 test2_winsorized test1_winsorized
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>
#>  1     1     0    57    82             82               57  
#>  2     2     0    77    80             80               68  
#>  3     3     0    67    90             82.8             67  
#>  4     4     0    15    70             70               15  
#>  5     5     0    58    72             72               58  
#>  6     6     1    18    44             44               18  
#>  7     7     1    44    44             44               44  
#>  8     8     1    18    46             46               18  
#>  9     9     1    20    44             44               20  
#> 10    10     1    14    38             43.4             14.9
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>